# Killing Blender processes

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, workflow

So I'm currently using Java's ProcessBuilder to run Blender Python scripts for rendering in the background and that's working fine. However, I would also like to abort Blender at any time, and unless if I'm mistaken, killing the blender.exe processes would be the best method of doing this.

So I tried using the destroy() method on the process that runs Blender, only to find that Blender actually starts two processes. Using the destroy() method only kills one of the two processes (and not the one that's doing the actual rendering). Does anyone know of a good workaround or another method of implementing a render abort? Thanks!

Comment: post your java code or follow the links here (your question is not clearly  Blender related and might be better placed at SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269494/how-can-i-cause-a-child-process-to-exit-when-the-parent-does

Comment: If you are on Windows, you could `taskkill /f /t /im "blender.exe"` (`/t` means [kill tree](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html), so also child processes). There are probably similar solutions for OSX and Linux, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java for instance.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can kill Blender easily by opening the *task manager*,then selecting "end process".

You would not need to use python.

Here's a pic:

[image]

You can access task manager by pressing <kbd>CTRL+ALT+DELETE</kbd>.

On Mac, you can do just about the same thing, just this is done in the *activity monitor* Instead.

Comment: `killall blender` on linux

Comment: @batFINGER `$ killall blender` doesn't work for me